# Animate window from right to left[Titanium]

Tags: animation, window, titanium, slide

I want to animate a window so that it slides to right to open and slides to the left to close. How can i do that ?

I have the following code but ti doesn't work :

```
 var textWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  width:400,
  height:400,
  backgroundColor:'white',
  borderColor:'blue',
  borderRadius:10,
  left:0,
  right:0,
  bottom:600,
});

var slideRightopen = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
slideRightopen.right = 320; 
slideRightopen.duration = 200;


var slideLeftClose = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
slideLeftClose.right = 0;
slideLeftClose.duration = 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the bottom to `600` will display the window off screen

Comment: bottom of the window ?